# Change background on click and have link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to combine this two codes :

1. I want the user to click on the link and be redirected to a site with the chose background color
2. From within that page now it reloads the entire page if user wants to change the color again

Is there a way I can load it faster or have the older code I was using combined?

```
<div class="box1">     
 <ul id="bgbg">
  <li id="bg1"><a href="www.example.com#red"></a> </li>
  <li id="bg2"><a href="www.example.com#blue"></a> </li>
  <li id="bg3"><a href="www.example.com#green"></a> </li
</ul></div>


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var matchColors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
 var color = window.location.hash.slice(1);
 if (matchColors.indexOf(color) != -1){
    jQuery('body').addClass(color);
}
});
```

OLDER CODE :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
 jQuery( "#bgbg > li" ).click(function() {      
 jQuery( 'body' ).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3');      
 jQuery( 'body' ).addClass(jQuery(this).attr('id')) ;   });});
```

But I had to remove it since I couldn't link that background.

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 0):

I have minor changes to your code, to achieve what you are looking for. Check and try the below code:

```js
$(".colorSelector a").on('click', function() {
  var colorSelected = $(this).data('color');
  $('body').removeAttr('class').addClass(colorSelected);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">
  <ul id="bgbg" class="colorSelector">
    <li id="bg1">
      <a href="www.example.com#red" data-color='red'>red</a>
    </li>
    <li id="bg2">
      <a href="www.example.com#blue" data-color='blue'>blue</a>
    </li>
    <li id="bg3">
      <a href="www.example.com#green" data-color='green'>green</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the current URL path is the same as the clicked URL path. If they are the same you can apply your add class jQuery. Your jquery that checks the URLS hash value can just sit inside your `$(document).ready` so it triggers when the page is visited. I have changed the lists ID's to the colours to make the code simpler, but it might be better to use the data attribute approach for the click event outlined by [Milan Chheda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44613568/8085668).

I can't do a working example because it requires you to redirect to another page, so you will need to check it your end.

**CSS**

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box1">
  <ul id="bgbg" class="colorSelector">
    <li id="red">
      <a href="www.example.com#red">red</a>
    </li>
    <li id="blue">
      <a href="www.example.com#blue">blue</a>
    </li>
    <li id="green">
      <a href="www.example.com#green">green</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // add class to body on page load depending on link hash
  var matchColors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
  var color = window.location.hash.slice(1);
  if (matchColors.indexOf(color) != -1){
     $('body').addClass(color);
  }
  // add class to body based on list items ID
  $( "#bgbg > li" ).click(function() {
    // get current URLs relative path exluding hash
    var currentURL = window.location.pathname;
    // get clicked links relative URL path exluding hash
    var linkURL = $(this).find('a')[0].pathname;
    // check if the clicked link URL path is the same as the current URL path
    if(currentURL == linkURL) {
      // apply relevent classes
      $( 'body' ).removeClass('red blue green');
      $( 'body' ).addClass(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
    }
  });
});
```